# What's the difference between a model and a $\sigma$ structure?

Tags: model-theory

In model theory, I haven't actually seen the word "model" defined. The only thing I've seen defined is a $\sigma$ structure for some signature $\sigma$.

I read phrases like $A$ is a model of some theory, where $A$ is a $\sigma$ structure. What is the difference? Is a model just a $\sigma$ structure?

The first time I see model defined is in "canonical model", which just gives a specific $\sigma$ structure.

I am reading Hodge's A Shorter Model Theory.

I think a model is just a $\sigma$ structure that satisfies a certain set of formulae (a theory).

Comment: A model is a $\sigma$ structure which satisfies some axioms (the "theory").

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So I am right that a model is just a $\sigma$ structure that *models* a set of formulae/axioms?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If you confirm this in an answer you have a shiny 25 reputation points waiting for you, as I'm sure is just *so* important. ;)

Comment: I honestly don't get why I got two downvotes, and one very recently. Would they care to explain?

Comment: I thought that model was two things, 1) a set of propositions $\Sigma$ and 2) a truth assignment on the atoms $A$ such that all proposition $\Sigma \subset Prop(A)$ are true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

- A *model* of a theory $\mathcal{T}$ over a signature $\sigma$ is a $\sigma$-structure $A$ such that $A \vDash \mathcal{T}$, i.e. every statement in $\mathcal{T}$ is true in $A$.
- Therefore, the following are equivalent statements: "$A$ is a $\sigma$-structure", and "$A$ is a model of $\varnothing$".

See also [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24218/does-the-definition-of-model-depend-on-a-theory-or-just-a-signature).

Comment: Isn't $\sigma$ usually a signature, not a language?

Comment: @avid19 I am used to texts where "language" is used for your "signature", however, according to your definition of signature I believe you are right.

Comment: In Hodge's A Shorter Model Theory, he defines a signature to be all the non logical symbols, and a language is the signature, including the logical symbols.

Comment: @avid19 OK, I have updated the answer to follow that convention. The convention I am used to is that the language does not include the logical symbols either.

Comment: Thanks for the help, enjoy those 25 reputation points :)

Answer (score 3):

*Structure* is the official term. A structure is a set equipped with certain functions and relations that correspond to the symbols of a signature (also called language, depending on the author).

The term *model* is officially only defined for speaking about the relation between a structure and a theory: A structure is a model of a theory if it satisfies all sentences in the theory.

But in reality, outside lectures for beginners almost nobody says *structure*. We tend to call the things *model*, even when there is no theory around. This phenomenon is similar to how most people call the Netherlands *Holland*, or say *America* for the United States of America, except in contexts where this can lead to confusion.